# Java's socket.localPort() always reports -1

Tags: java, sockets

I have some code which needs to know the local port it uses to connect to a server.

The Socket.localPort() call always seems to return -1. Also, do a Socket.toString() returns something like "port=33031,localport=-1" - again, with a -1.

Does anyone know why this, and how to get the local side port number? I am GNU Classpath 0.97.2 - is this just an API bug or do I not understand this call?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the Socket class from java.net package, it returns a -1 if the socket is not bound yet. The method is not a static method and is goes by the name, getLocalPort not just localPort. In GNU Classpath, -1 most probably means the same thing.

Comment: hmm... well i am definitely connected and sending data back & forth. Plus i see it in wireshark. Right, .getLocalPort() is what i mean... I am using a SocketChannel - do sc.socket().getLocalPort()